# Detect nested path and redirect to home with RewriteRule

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I already find the way to get the OK, with http://htaccess.mwl.be/ tool,  redirect to *home* with this RewriteRule. But I get Status Code: **404**, for that URL on the web page after update .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/extensiones-de-pelo.*$ /? [R=301,L]

- new URL is https://test.example.com/
- Test are stopped, a redirect will be made with status code 301
```

For this full URL:

```
https://test.example.com/wp-content/themes/extensiones-de-pelo/core/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.7.2
```

I need that work with only one part of the full path:

```
RewriteRule ^extensiones-de-pelo.*$ /? [R=301,L]  // This rule was not met.
```

Can someone help me please, Regards, Romel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your URL is not starting with `extensiones-de-pelo` so that regex won't work. Check it against `%{REQUEST_URI}` so you can know if it maches with the keyword.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} extensiones-de-pelo
RewriteRule .* /? [R=301,L]
```